Need help identifying Bluetooth speaker component
I have a portable Bluetooth speaker, the only branding it has is "Model: 886". It is not turning on. I opened it and identified a burned 3-leg IC. It's code I think is Mxx0C, x is unreadable.



In the third photo, the yellow is the 0V cable coming from the battery and the green is the power-on switch.

The first two or three digits of the Mxx0C marking, i.e. Mx or Mxx, are what's going to help with identifying the device, the rest are likely date codes for the device. With that being said, it will take a substantial amount time to identify this SOT23-3 chip. Silergy is known to have five digits on their SOT23-3 devices.
